# Holes in bbq wall

Tags: hole-repair

I have a Brinkman bbq, there are holes in back wall where heat shield brackets were located. There are 5 holes each approx 2" long and 1/2" high. Is there a fix?

Comment: ...Replace the missing brackets? Or weld a plate on, but how practical that is will depend on the materials (cast aluminum is difficult to weld in the best of circumstances, sheet steel is easy, in either case assuming you know who to weld and have an appropriate machine to weld with.)

Comment: Are these holes created by rust or holes that are there originally for ventilation? A picture would be helpful.

Comment: a fix for what? ... you have not identified a problem